# data.frame from a list and call object from string

Tags: r

I wanted to replicate a table from Tsay's financial time series book and realized that even though I am able to do it, my code seems clumsy and fill with bad practices.
I tried a bit with plyr but didn't really work for me.

So this is my code:

```
library(fBasics)

url= 'http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/fts3/d-ibm3dx7008.txt'

table1.2 = read.table(url,header=T)
l1=lapply(table1.2,basicStats)
naml1 = names(l1)
datmat = as.data.frame(matrix(0,nrow=nrow(l1$Date),ncol=4))

nams = names(l1)
j=1

for( i in nams){
 datmat[,j] = eval(parse(text=paste("l1",i,sep="$")))
 j=j+1
  }

rownames(datmat)= rownames(l1[[1]])
colnames(datmat)=colnames(table1.2)
```

I don't care about summary statistics of Date, so just get rid of it.

```
datmat =datmat[,-1]
```

So I heard that the eval(parse(text= should be avoided as possible. I tried with the function get but didn't work.

I am just trying to start getting rid of bad programming practices, so any advice is more than welcome.

Answer (score 7):

Why go through all that.  it appears you're doing what the function basicStats already does.  This seems too simple to be right but I think the following gives you the same output:

```
basicStats(table1.2)[,-1]
```

Comment: Jeez, the approving comment gets more up-votes than the answer? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, I tried to figure out what you want to do, but other than reading your dataset I could not get what you want to do. Still though, I try to come up with some advice. Maybe I could help a little further if you'd edit your post an get a little more precise.

1. Use <- instead of = when assigning variables. It's the R way to do it.
2. If you do not use [RStudio](http://rstudio.org/) already, go an get it, it will help you a lot, since it has  nice autocomplete, and good help integration. (you can use alt+ - to get <- in rstudio, to help you get used to it)
3. R is a vectorized language, often you do not need loops, E.g.: `paste(l1,nams,sep="$")` works without the loop.
4. You are already using lapply, that's nice. Often it works well to write a function and then combine this own function with `lapply` and use it on our data.
5. It's really worth the read through some of the better introductions, or also scan through more advanced ressources – even if they are not covering your particular problem. Take your time to do it it is well worth it.

   Here's a related discussion on [crossvalidated (stackexchange's stats site)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138/resources-for-learning-r)

Answer (score 0):

You could just add this after you get `l1`

```
datmat  <- setNames(as.data.frame(l1), names(l1))
```

A simpler approach would be using the `describe` function in the `psych` package

```
psych::describe(table1.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of equal length vectors into a data.frame very easily and then just change the names

```
> df.stats <- as.data.frame(lapply(table1.2,basicStats)[-1])
Warning message:
In sum(X) : Integer overflow - use sum(as.numeric(.))
> names(df.stats) <- names(table1.2)[-1]
> str(df.stats)
'data.frame':   16 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ rtn   : num  9.84e+03 0.00 -2.30e-01 1.32e-01 -8.57e-03 ...
 $ vwretd: num  9.84e+03 0.00 -1.71e-01 1.15e-01 -4.25e-03 ...
 $ ewretd: num  9.84e+03 0.00 -1.04e-01 1.07e-01 -2.57e-03 ...
 $ sprtr: num  9.84e+03 0.00 -2.05e-01 1.16e-01 -4.87e-03 ...
```

Ends up exactly like what you constructed.